# How to get list elements to global workspace

Tags: r, list

Say I have a list like `my.list <- list(a=10, df=data.frame(a=2,b=3,r=5), c=as.Date('2001-01-10'))` (my.list has undefined number of elements)

What function can I use/code so that `a,b,c` are known as variable in the global workspace ? I mean a,b c should be objects

Comment: It's like opening your drawer and throwing everything in it on the floor, why would you want to do that?

Comment: To not have to open the drawer each time I want to use something in it

Comment: If you could be more specific, maybe we could point you to better approaches. Using `with` for example, which is like living in your drawer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list2env(my.list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: And with a slightly different behavior (reversible and no copying/overwriting), have a look at `attach.`